# how to execute market app with search from qrcode

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, app-store, qr-code

i need to search any named app from using android market, app store, windows phone market. 
My goal is

1. Generate qrcode by any schema url with any app name
2. Read qrcode from mobile
3. follow schema url to open Market (app store) app to search by app name

Is there possible?

Please tell me scheme url in (Android, iOS, Windows Phone)?

Answer (score 1):

From Android app:

```
market://details?id=<package_name>
```

Comment: I dont have `ID`, i have only `name`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach it.

You don't know whether the person scanning the code has Android, iOS, or WP7.

Create a code with the following URL

```
http://example.com/?app=AppName
```

The user will scan the code.

The user will open her web browser.

Your web server will look at the phone's User Agent String and decide if she is using WP7, Android, iOS or something else.

If the user's phone is recognised, immediately perform an HTTP 302 redirect.

For Android, redirect to:

```
https://play.google.com/store/search?q=AppName
```

For iOS, redirect to:

```
http://itunes.com/AppName
```

For Windows Phone 7, redirect to:

```
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/search?q=AppName
```

For all other phones, redirect to your main page - or have a page which tells the user that her phone isn't compatible.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play

This is old style.
market://details?id=<package_name>

It can be crash if playstore application is not in the device.

The below is safer.
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>

> If you want to link to your products from an Android app, create an Intent that opens a URL. As you configure this intent, pass "com.android.vending" into Intent.setPackage() so that users see your app's details in the Google Play Store app instead of a chooser.

> The following example directs users to viewing the app containing the package name com.example.android in Google Play: